# Wordpress admin is not opening

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I open my website admin `https://www.examplesite.com/wp-admin`
it is redirecting to homepage.

Comment: Can you please `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your  `wp-configue.php` and check what is error?

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: This answer was using the original URL as given by OP, and later edited/removed by David.

It works fine for me - presenting the admin login screen as expected, so maybe too many bad logins from your IP / address and it's therefore redirecting you.

Try logging in from a friends computer or via Tor Browser and then reset the list of banned IPs?

Or if you have access to the database (*and knowledge thereof*) you can clear the table of bad login attempts to re-enable your usual access.